# requesting general guidance on how to create something

Tags: discussion

I am wondering if this is an appropriate question for stackoverflow

I want to recreate the functionality of the slider on [Facebooks Paper homepage](https://www.facebook.com/paper) if you click to the first slide you will see what I am refering to.

basically there are 4 videos each video is split up into a series of smaller sections that can be toggled through using the sliders controls when the end of the last section is reached the next click brings you to the start of the next video.

If I was to provide a brief of the exact functionality I wanted to recreate and the technologies I want to use is asking for a starting point and direction for my research an appropriate question for stackoverflow?

Comment: Sounds too broad.  The scope should really be targeted such that it's clear what is/isn't a sufficient answer, and where a sufficient answer isn't excessively long.

Comment: Good point so maybe an individual question for each 'feature' as I come up against a problem with its implemenation would be better

Comment: Google is an excellent resource for research like this: http://www.queness.com/post/12454/everything-you-need-to-create-full-screen-video-and-image-website.

Comment: Thanks I have tried to google to find examples of how they split up each video but havn't been able to.  The full size video / image being responsive is not what I think will be the problem its the javascript that will allow me to split each video up into sections and having text animate relative to those sections

Comment: +1 for asking first.  However, no.  These questions often devolve into linkfests that rot in time and attracts spammers.  "Here's a tutorial", "use this control", "my product makes your weener hard", etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would advise against posting this on Stack Overflow. There are so many questions asking "how do I create this aspect of Facebook" that it will probably get shut down very quickly. This will happen for a couple of reasons.

First, this question would be rather broad since you are basically asking for advice. That would probably end up being the close reason. More than that, users are a little wary of always seeing these types of Facebook requests and tend to pounce on them a little more than the average "how do I start making X?".

I would suggest doing your own research, perhaps look at some white papers from Facebook, and then narrow your topic down considerably into parts. Figure out a part which can be well defined, and then if you attempt to implement it or follow a tutorial and get stuck, you can post a well written, well research question and should get help fairly quickly.

I hesitate to suggest asking for an approach on Programmers because that is and also is not what that site is for. If you were able to narrow this down to a *very* specific subset and had more questions about a design pattern or development methodology for implementing that approach then Programmers may fit.

As it stands, asking general guidance is not really a good fit for the Q&A model of Stack Overflow.

Comment: Excuse my ignorance but do you know where Facebook publishes its whitepapers?

Comment: @Ir1sh I'd be willing to bet Google knows.

Comment: Indeed I am clearly not the most advanced google user but I am aware of its existence and I think its fair to make the assumption that someone who uses this site and any of its family is aware of google and its uses.  a search for facebook whitepapers and a search of developers.facebook.com is not resulting in anything useful so far.